# Redirecionar dominio, usando configuração do provedor de dominio?

Tags: github, subdomínio

Eu tenho 2 domínios

`http://brunorozendo.com.br` e `http://brunorozendo.com`

O `http://brunorozendo.com.br` está hospedado no github.

Tem como fazer o `http://brunorozendo.com` redirecionar para o  `http://brunorozendo.com.br`

sem ter que envolver a hospedagem (usando apenas as configuração de disponíveis no provedor de domínio) ?

Comment: Você precisaria para isto setar o CNAME para algum DNS, neste caso se bem entendi seria para o GitHub. Achei uma discussão em um forum que fala o que acredito ser sua dúvida, veja se essa solução ajuda: www.hardmob.com.br/internet-redes-and-telefonia-fixa/444706-redirecionamento-de-dominio-hospedagem.html

Comment: Não server, ao acessar brunorozendo.com dá 404 no github, o objetivo mesmo é redirecionar.

Comment: Se você possuir os dados CNAME, etc do que você utilizou para hospedar o .com.br, coloque no painel do domínio os mesmos ips para o .com, desta maneira é para funcionar, já consegui isto em outros domínios.

Comment: Eu fiz o que essa [página disse](https://help.github.com/articles/tips-for-configuring-an-a-record-with-your-dns-provider/) para configurar o dominio, nesse caso foram feitas 2 entradas do tipo `A`

Comment: Eu não entendi/sei que dados são esse do CNAME ao qual o tu falou

Comment: Pelo que vi você ainda não conseguiu redimensionar o .com atualmente. Recentemente adquiri um domínio .com no site Whois, acredito ser um dos mais famosos, no próprio painel do Whois existe a opção de redirecionamento. Por onde você adquiriu seu domínio? Teste o meu `oregionalsul.com`